# ansible playbook to read name servers (DNS) from /etc/resolv.conf file

Tags: ansible

Please help me in writing ansible playbook to read name servers (DNS) from */etc/resolv.conf* file from multiple servers and write those name servers to a file.

I tried to get the contents into variable called `contents` as below:

```yaml
- name: check resolv.conf exists
  stat:
    path: /etc/resolv.conf
  register: resolv_conf
- name: check nameservers list in resolv.conf
  vars:
     contents: "{{ lookup('file', '/etc/resolv.conf') }}"
  when: resolv_conf.stat.exists == True
```

Then not sure how to proceed further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a regex, with the filter [`regex_findall`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#regular-expression-filters) in order to achieve this, especially considering that you might have more than one DNS server defined there.

***Mind that*** this will give you a list.

Given the playbook:

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no

  tasks:
    - name: check resolv.conf exists
      stat:
        path: /etc/resolv.conf
      register: resolv_conf
    - name: check nameservers list in resolv.conf
      debug:
        msg: "{{ contents }}"
      vars:
        contents: "{{ lookup('file', '/etc/resolv.conf') | regex_findall('\\s*nameserver\\s*(.*)') }}"
      when: resolv_conf.stat.exists == True
```

It gives, on an Alpine container, the recap:

```
PLAY [localhost] ***************************************************************

TASK [check resolv.conf exists] ************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [check nameservers list in resolv.conf] ***********************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        "192.168.65.1"
    ]
}

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Comment: Thank you for quick reply. It helps me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if it's exactly what you want, but you could write the contents into a file using the **lineinfile** than replace everything except the nameservers from there, using the **replace** module. Like this:

```
          - name: Check if resolv exists
            stat:
                    path: /etc/resolv.conf
            register: resolv_conf

          - set_fact:
                    content: "{{ lookup('file', '/etc/resolv.conf') }}"
            when: resolv_conf.stat.exists


          - name: Write them into a file
            lineinfile:
                    line: "{{ content }}"
                    create: yes
                    state: present
                    path: /tmp/resolv_conf_nameservers

          - name: Remove everything but nameservers
            replace:
                    path: /tmp/resolv_conf_nameservers
                    regexp:  "^(?!nameserver).*$"
                    replace: ""
```

~
Please note that you should use **set_fact** to load contents into a variable.

If you want the file containing the nameservers to be placed in your own machine/localhost, use **delegate_to** in the last two tasks:

```
          - name: Check if resolv exists
            stat:
                    path: /etc/resolv.conf
            register: resolv_conf

          - set_fact:
                    content: "{{ lookup('file', '/etc/resolv.conf') }}"
            when: resolv_conf.stat.exists


          - name: Write them into a file
            lineinfile:
                    line: "{{ content }}"
                    create: yes
                    state: present
                    path: /tmp/resolv_conf_nameservers
            delegate_to: localhost

          - name: Remove everything but nameservers
            replace:
                    path: /tmp/resolv_conf_nameservers
                    regexp:  "^(?!nameserver).*$"
                    replace: ""
            delegate_to: localhost
```

Comment: Exactly I wanted this. Thank you Vitor Carvalho.

Comment: If I want outputs from multiple servers into single file, what is the best way to do it?

Comment: Then run this playbook against several servers in your inventory. The playbook will append the contents into the file located in localhost. But in order to do that, don't forget the delegate_to: localhost tag.